# java paint method not being called

Tags: java, swing, graphics, repaint, paintcomponent

I make a game in java and I can't seem to call the `paintComponent()` method in my game. here's the code :

```
public class TwinMoonTowers extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private class TMTMenu extends MouseAdapter{
        private Icon start, shop, quit;
        private Icon main_bg;

        public TMTMenu (){
            System.out.println("starting menu...");

            start = new Icon(TMTConstant.START_SOURCE,
                        TMTConstant.START_COORD_X, TMTConstant.START_COORD_Y);

            shop = new Icon (TMTConstant.SHOP_SOURCE,
                        TMTConstant.SHOP_COORD_X, TMTConstant.SHOP_COORD_Y);

            quit = new Icon (TMTConstant.EXIT_SOURCE,
                        TMTConstant.EXIT_COORD_X, TMTConstant.EXIT_COORD_Y);

            main_bg = new Icon (TMTConstant.MAIN_MENU_BG, 0, 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){

            int x = me.getX();
            int y = me.getY();

            System.out.println("coord: "+x+","+y);

            if (me.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
                if (x > start.x && x < start.x + start.getIcon().getWidth(null)
                        && y > start.y && y < start.y + start.getIcon().getHeight(null)){
                    curState = TMTConstant.MODE_STATE;
                }
                else if (x > quit.x && x < quit.x + quit.getIcon().getWidth(null)
                        && y > quit.y && y < quit.y + quit.getIcon().getHeight(null)){
                    curState = TMTConstant.EXIT_STATE;
                }
                else if (x > shop.x && x < shop.x + shop.getIcon().getWidth(null)
                        && y > shop.y && y < shop.y + shop.getIcon().getHeight(null)){
                    curState = TMTConstant.SHOP_STATE;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private class TMTModeSelector extends MouseAdapter{
        private Icon TwinTower, TripleTower, back;

        public TMTModeSelector(){

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){

        }
    }

    private String testDebug;
    private int curState;
    private TMTMenu menu;

    public TwinMoonTowers (){
        menu = new TMTMenu();
        curState = TMTConstant.MAIN_MENU_STATE;

        System.out.println("creating panel..");

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.setSize(TMTConstant.WINDOW_WIDTH, TMTConstant.WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        this.addMouseListener(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.repaint();

    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        System.out.println("preparing canvas..");

        switch(curState){
            case TMTConstant.MAIN_MENU_STATE :
                g2d.drawImage(menu.main_bg.getIcon(), menu.main_bg.x, menu.main_bg.y, this);
                g2d.drawImage(menu.start.getIcon(), menu.start.x, menu.start.y, null);
                g2d.drawImage(menu.quit.getIcon(), menu.quit.x, menu.quit.y, null);
                g2d.drawImage(menu.shop.getIcon(), menu.shop.x, menu.shop.y, null);
                break;
            case TMTConstant.GAME_STATE :
                break;
            case TMTConstant.SHOP_STATE :
                break;
            case TMTConstant.MODE_STATE :
                break;
        }

        System.out.print("render image...");

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();

    }
}
```

while class Icon is this:

```
public class Icon{

private Image pic;
public int x, y;

public Icon (String path, int x, int y){

    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon (path);
    pic = ii.getImage();

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public Image getIcon() {return pic;}
}
```

the basics here is to draw a menu containing 3 buttons (start, shop, exit)

but, the paintComponent method is not called (the system.out.println not showing)

Comment: what is TMTConstant here ?? ...

Comment: TMTConstant is a class with constants...like window width, height, etc.

Comment: Note that @ShaikMd will not be notified of your comment (which is better edited into the question) unless you add '@ Their Name' (no spaces) to the comment.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: here's the java project I've uploaded http://www.mediafire.com/?hj9k4s003zr4nga been struggling for an hour but no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
g.dispose();
```

These lines are unnecessary (might even be wrong), remove them.

The problem is most likely not in the code you posted. Where do you add the panel to a top level window (frame/applet)? What layout do you use for its content pane? My guess is the size is (0,0) so the panel won't be painted.

Comment: I addad the panel to a jframe... but I haven't set the layout (probably null layout). the size of the frame is the same as the panel

Comment: here's a strange one. whenever I move the frame until it pass my laptop screen, it renders....but only the part that is cut by the laptop screen.... Ive checked your solution and removed the code,but it still the same